# createBitmap not creating full width bitmap

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying create a Bitmap which will occupy the full width and I have this simple code.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int w = metrics.widthPixels;
    int h = metrics.heightPixels;
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    mCanvas.drawColor(0xff00ff00);

    mImageview = new ImageView(this);
    mImageview.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
    setContentView(mImageview);
}
```

This does not seem to be creating the full width bitmap. I have some space left over on either sides. What should I do to fill those gaps and what I am doing incomplete in the above code?

[image]

Comment: Does your activity layout have any sort of padding or margins on the sides? Depending on your environment, padding or margins may be added by default to a new layout.

Comment: @TylerMacDonell - I have removed any references to any xml above. Where would that magical padding come, if there is any?

Comment: Woops, I didn't notice that. My mistake!